# Случайные числа в C++

Tags: c++

Помогите создать программу, чтобы при нажатии на определенную кнопку, он выдавал числа по рандому, с нажатием кнопки я разобрался, вот выложил код, а как сделать чтобы он не прибавлял +5, а просто каждый раз выдавал разные цифры. Я прочитал статьи про рандом в интернете, но не понял к сожалению, там не на доступном языке и непонятно.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int b=0; char c;

    while ((c=getch()) !='q')
    {
        if (c=='a') {
            b+=5;

            cout << b << endl;
        }
    }

    system ("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

В C++11 есть классы для генерации случайных чисел:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

std::default_random_engine rng;

int my_random(int a, int b)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist_a_b(a, b);
    return dist_a_b(rng);
}

int main()
{
    rng.seed(std::random_device()());
    std::cout << my_random(0, 42);
}
```

- [`uniform_int_distribution`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

Answer (score 5):

Еще добавлю, что, так как вывод этого числа заключен в цикл, можно использовать случайное число относительно текущего времени. Это делается примерно так:
подключаем библиотеки

> `#include <time.h> и #include <stdlib.h>`

затем генерируем случайное число, предварительно создав переменную текущего момента времени t:

> `time_t t;
> srand((unsigned) time(&t));
> int random = rand()%MAX;`

Вот недавно проверил, полностью рабочий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
void main(){
    int MAX = 10;
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    int random = rand()%MAX;
    cout<<random<<endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Вот такой код дает последовательность {2,1,9,3,0,5,6,0,4,8} - в общем-то случайная последовательность, не возрастающая! Код следующий:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
void main(){
    int MAX = 10;
    int i=0;
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    while(i!=10){
    int random = rand()%MAX;
    cout<<random<<endl;
    i++;}
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: можно вопрос? почему всякий раз когда я использую рандом, при компиляции у меня появляется вкладка stdlib.h а внутри этой вкладки ошибка какая то, т.е ответ в терминале он не выдает!

Comment: Можете выложить свой код, чтобы можно было посмотреть? Можно прямо в вопрос добавить (править)!

Comment: а он только состоит из вашего кода, указывает вот на эту ошибку: _CRTIMP int __cdecl rand (void);

Comment: Все ОК, Только time_t t здесь совершенно излишен. Можно просто time(NULL)

Comment: Полностью с вами согласен, можно без этой строчки! Просто как-то привык ее использовать, и вот по привычке написал...

Comment: все отлично, прикрепил его к другому коду, работает, но ... как я тут заметил он тут не совсем рандом, он секунды тут считает, time, а как сделать чтобы он выдавал как в паскале, т.е тут нет такой последовательности, например, (5,1,9,3) тут идет по строгому возрастанию, это можно исправить или нет?

Comment: time() тут совсем для другой цели служит. Не парься, пока поверь на слово. Все в порядке.

Comment: нет, кода нет у меня, просто вопрос, можно сделать так чтобы рандом он взял не по возрастанию, а вразброску? т.е не так (1,3,4,7,9) а так (1,5,2,7,4) ?

Comment: какой версии? я не вижу никакой Вашей версии

Comment: На самом деле он берет не по возрастанию, а именно в разноброс, на то он и рандом... Другое дело, что сам генератор случайных чисел не такой уж "рандомный", то есть иногда выпадают и одинаковые числа в подряд, и возможно выпадение такой возрастающей последовательности... Но все это явления случайные! Можете посмотреть на моем примере (в самом ответе)

Answer (score 4):

Как получать в С++ случайные числа. Пример.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

srand (time (NULL));
int rand_num = rand();
```

Comment: Выдает ошибки:

1)`random' undeclared (first use this function)
2)`srandom' undeclared (first use this function) 
3) In function `int main(int, char**)':

Comment: Забыл, это линуксовые функции. переправил ответ на стандартные. должно заработать.

Comment: можно вопрос? почему всякий раз когда я использую рандом, при компиляции у меня появляется вкладка stdlib.h а внутри этой вкладки ошибка какая то, т.е ответ в терминале он не выдает!

Comment: не знаю. какая среда программирования?

Comment: с++, на dev c++, windows 7

Comment: 342 строка, а в вашем коде разве есть она? вот эта ошибка на 342 строке: too many arguments to function `int rand()'